# A little complex compose of mouseover and mouseout

Tags: jquery

How can i change this function:

```
 $('#myContent').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event){
    if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
      $('#editContent').show();
    } else {
      $('#editContent').hide();
      }
   });
```

if i want `$('#editContent')` to be show on mouseover on `$('#myContent')`, but then it should be hiden only if `$('#myContent')` has event mouseover and `$('#editContent')` has mouseover?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. The last part does not make sense. Both elements cannot have `mouseover` at the same time..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One question, do you have to use the event "live"? Since I don't know how your HTML is implemented, I can just assume things.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nP7QY/)

Above is an example how you can achieve this. As I assume you do not append "editContent" and "myContent" dynamically, I use event "hover" instead.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

So, when hovering over `#myContent`, `#editContent` has to be shown. Then, `#editContent` has only to be hidden when the mouse is not at `#myContent` or `#editContent`. See:

```
(function(){
    var delay;
    var editContent = $('#editContent');
    $('#myContent').live('mouseover', function(){
        editContent.show();
    }).live('mouseout', function(){
        clearTimeout(delay); //Prevent stacked timeouts
        delay = setTimeout(function(){ //Set timeout
            editContent.hide();
        }, 300); //Activate hider after 300ms
    });
    editContent.live('mouseenter', function(){
       clearTimeout(delay); //Clear hider, to keep the element visible
    });
})();
```