# jQuery live function with setTimeout

Tags: jquery, live, settimeout, mouseenter

I'm trying to combine mouseenter, live and setTimeout function to make some animations

```
$(".kundenList li").live("mouseenter", function(){
    if ($(this).children().length > 0) {
        $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout( function () {
            $(this).children("div.description").css({opacity: '0'});

            $(this).children("div.blacklayer").animate({
                opacity: '0.85'
            }, 300);

            $(this).children("div.description").animate({
                top: "-=200px",
                opacity: '1'
            }, 300).css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );

            $(this).addClass("activeLI");
        }, 300));
    }
});
```

Html looks like this

```
<ul class="kundenList">
    <li>
        <img src="t3.png" class="kundenImg" />
        <div class="blacklayer" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
        <div class="description">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Since I'm posting the question scrip apparently doesn't work :) . Anyone know why? Thanks.

PS I need live function since I'm loading new content over ajax

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages. If I remove setTimeout function everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` inside `setTimeout` is referring to the global `window` object. Store a reference to `this` in a temporary variable, as shown below. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/de7Fg/**

```
$(".kundenList li").live("mouseenter", function(){
    var $this = $(this); //Reference to `$(this)`

    if ($this.children().length > 0) {
        $this.data('timeout', setTimeout( function () {
            // $this points to $(this), as defined previously
            $this.children("div.description").css({opacity: '0'});

            $this.children("div.blacklayer").animate({
                opacity: '0.85'
            }, 300);

            $this.children("div.description").animate({
                top: "-=200px",
                opacity: '1'
            }, 300).css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );

            $this.addClass("activeLI");
        }, 300));
    }
});
```

Comment: Goldie, Rob was faster than me. Please accept his answer. If you hover your cursor over answer time you can see exact answer time and he is 5 seconds faster than me

Comment: `timeout` does work. It's executing the function **ONCE** after 300 milliseconds. Are you confusing `setTimeout` with `setInterval`?

Comment: Ok... I see that it works now. Thing is that I need to executhe the function IF mouseenter last at least 300 milliseconds

Comment: I have already answered that question at another post. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850058/a-little-complex-compose-of-mouseover-and-mouseout/7850129#7850129

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access `li` with `this` inside timeout function. Before timeout function define a variable, assing `$(this)` to it and use it in function like this ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/kUbct/)):

```
$(".kundenList li").live("mouseenter", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.children().size() > 0) {

        $this.data('timeout', setTimeout( function () {
            $this.children("div.description").css({opacity: '0'});

            $this.children("div.blacklayer").animate({
                opacity: '0.85'
            }, 300);

            $this.children("div.description").animate({
                top: "-=200px",
                opacity: '1'
            }, 300).css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );

            $this.addClass("activeLI");
        }, 300));
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you check the example? http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/kUbct/ it's working. Did you add some other code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kUbct/1/ I added some css. Script supossed to work 300 (now i changed to 500) ms ater you mouseenter the elemet. Now it's woring instantly when you mouseenter the elemet.

Comment: 300 ms or 500 ms, it's too fast, make it 5000 to see that it's working.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't expressed my problem well.
Thing is that I need to executhe the function IF mouseenter last at least 300 milliseconds